# Mix content: requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint in Vue JS

Tags: laravel, vue.js

[error image](https://i.ibb.co/C6FV7Jc/picturemessage-3s0ahavo-34e.png)

Hi, I am working on Vue js and my all route links working fine but when I want to add a product this error show on the console, update and delete product functionality working fine. There is some problem here when adding product **"public"** is included in the URL as shown in error. Does someone know about this type of error and solution?

```
            editProduct() {
                this.form.put((`/auth/products/${this.form.id}`))
                    .then(response => {
                        $('#addNew').modal('hide');
                        Toast.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: 'Product updated successfully'
                        });
                        this.getResults();
                    });
            },
            addProduct() {
                this.form.post('/auth/products/')
                    .then(response => {
                        $('#addNew').modal('hide');
                        Toast.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: 'Product added successfully'
                        });
                        localStorage.setItem('productCount', response.data.products);
                        this.$emit('loggedIn');
                        this.products.data.push(response.data.data);
                    });
            },
```

Above code snippet, edit product working fine but add product throw mixed content error.

Comment: It looks like your page is trying to load something using HTTP while it was initially loaded in https. I'd check what part of the code is making that request and why is it in http. Check this more for info (https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content)

Comment: @AndD see my code above I edited my question

Comment: The action of your form is in http or https?

Comment: I am using **npm i axios vform** this package

Comment: Please [edit] to provide the error message as text, in the question itself.